# Why do I get "consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by" and "variable used within its own initial variable"

Tags: xcode, swift

The code errors are where it says `if let urlPath = urlPathString`.
Is there a problem if I put code of many view controllers in only one .swift file or do I have to put more .swift files?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, iCarouselDataSource, iCarouselDelegate {

    let avPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    var avPlayer:AVPlayer?
    let urlPathString:String? = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("spain", ofType: "mp4")

    if let urlPath = urlPathString {
        let movieUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlPath)
        self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: movieUrl)
        self.avPlayerViewController.player = self.avPlayer
    }

    //Este es el primero
    var imageArray : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    // estse es el segundo

    @IBOutlet weak var DisplayView: iCarousel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageArray = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg", "6.jpg","7.jpg", "8.jpg", "9.jpg","10.jpg","11.jpg","13.jpg"]
        DisplayView.type = iCarouselType.Cylinder
        DisplayView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Executable code, like `if let urlPath = ...`, cannot go at the top level of a class declaration like you have it. It must go *inside a function declaration*.